# Svelte Update Array by Reference

Tags: svelte

In Svelte I tried to update an array by reference.

I would like to dynamically pass it by reference and add a selected image by the user.

Each time the user selects an image it is loaded and added to the array, then the cycle will display the list of images uploaded.

I don't obtain the result expect, the `_1_3_1_imgs` array passed by reference is not updated, it is empty each time.

I tried to understand how Svelte works with properties but no success.

Can someone help?

```html
<script>
  let _1_3_1_imgs = [];
  let input;

  function addImg(images) {  
    
  let image;
    
  const file = input.files[0]; 

  if (file) {
   const reader = new FileReader();
   reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    image = reader.result;
   console.log(image);                
  });
  images =  [image, ...images];
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

return;
    }
  }
</script>

<input bind:this={input} on:change={() => addImg(_1_3_1_imgs)} type="file"/>                
{#each _1_3_1_imgs as _1_3_1_img, index}
  <div>
    <img src="{_1_3_1_img}" alt="Preview"/>         
  </div>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code. The first is that the function `addImage` is making no attempt to modify the array at all.

When the function is called, the parameter `images` contains a reference to the array you want to modify. When you write `images = [image, ...images]` you overwrite what's inside `images` and that reference is lost. Now you have no way to modify the array. If you wanna modify the array use something like `images.push(image)` or `images[images.length] = image`

The second problem is that you expect `_1_3_1_imgs` to be reactive but your code doesn't trigger any reactivity. [Reactivity in Svelte is triggered by assignments](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects). At no point in your code you are assigning a value to `_1_3_1_imgs` (it never appears on the left hand side of any assignment), so Svelte never bothers to check if the value changed and the each block is essentially ignored, as `_1_3_1_imgs` starts empty.

The third problem is that you only define `image` inside your callback, which means that until the callback runs you are dealing with `undefined`. Then, when you add `image` to `images` (happens outside of the callback) you may be adding `undefined`.